# Batch update with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm pulling data from a RETS(XML) feed and saving it in a local MongoDB using node and mongoose.

Periodically I need to update the documents and delete the inactive ones as well as add new ones. Rather than making multiple queries to Mongo or the RETS server, I was pulling both and looping through the data.

This works fine but is there a way to save the Mongoose results back to the database with updates and inserts? Or do I need to find each document and update it individually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On MongoDB, to update multiple documents (not just one) using Mongoose you can use the **multi** option:

```js
Model.updateMany({ 
  size: 'lage'
}, { 
  $set: { size: 'large' }
});
```

See more on in the Mongoose documentation for [updating documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating) and [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)

Comment: But I will be doing hundreds or maybe thousands of documents. Is batch updating this way possible?

Comment: Yes, you can put the `{ multi: true }` option. As described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-update)

Comment: How can I update the fields in a bulk? ex-users.email, users.address, users.first, etc. In this case, I have a users object. I do not want to mention each field. I want something like {$set: {"users.$.": users}}

Comment: @VikasChauhan well you have to specify which user you want to update the email to right? or you want to make all the user's emails, addresses, etc. the same?

Comment: @GianfrancoP. it will be for the only single user, I have specified in the condition.
If I am updating a single column    {$set: {'users.$.field': fieldvalue}} then it will be will work totally fine but when there are multiple values then, in that case, it is not working.
but I found a way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: @zeion this is a single function. Moongoose now supports Promises. So if you `await` the `update()` function and don't pass a callback function it will work as expected. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, If any one has multiple query conditions and  want to add new fields for every matching documents of query condition then we can go with

```
var bulk = Person.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find(query1).update(update1);
bulk.find(query2).update(update2);
bulk.execute(callback);
```

In following documentation, it is said that `db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()`

> Initializes and returns a new Bulk() operations builder for a
> collection. The builder constructs an unordered list of write
> operations that MongoDB executes in bulk. MongoDB executes in
> parallel the write operations in the list.

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/

Comment: In the update, how can you reference the document being updated?