# Mongoose: Effective method to iterate over records to update date values from a given array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the ids of products as array and I want to add 6 months to each date of the products which is in array

**my solution:**

```js
for(let product of product_id_array){
    db.Product.update({"_id" : product.id},{$set: { "endDate" : "add 6 months"}})
}
```

**the array is in this format:**

```
product_id_array = [{id: "5fdbc7fafff547f06b4d8bfd"}, {id: "e5dbc7fafff547f06b4d8bfd"}]
```

Do we have any other way for this? like putting array inside the update query to execute faster instead of loop?

Comment: hey Noor, have you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161538/batch-update-with-mongoose

Comment: Yes but that is still should be inside for loop.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that if you do the bulk update, you will have one single call to MongoDB with all the changes, instead of one call per change.